# Implicit Getters and Setters not created for me

Tags: coldfusion, getter-setter, coldfusion-10

I started playing with the new cfproperty stuff added in ColdFusion 9, but the primary piece that I want to use doesn't seem to work now in ColdFusion 10. I created the following CFC:

```
component displayName="Sources" {
  /**
  * @getter true
  * @setter true
  * @type numeric
  * @default 1
  **/
  property sourceid;
  /**
  * @getter true
  * @setter true
  * @type numeric
  * @default 1
  **/
  property sourcegroup;

  public any function init () {
    This.domainRegex = '\/\/(www\.)?(([A-Za-z0-9\-_]+\.?)+)';
    return this;
  }
}
```

When I dump the meta data for the CFC I can see the properties, but no methods created for them and I can't call `getSourceId()` or `getSourceGroup()`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try this:

```
component accessors="true" displayName="Sources" {
    property name="sourceid" type="numeric" default="1";
    property name="sourcegroup" type="numeric" default="1";
    public any function init () {
        this.domainRegex = '\/\/(www\.)?(([A-Za-z0-9\-_]+\.?)+)';
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: IT was the accessors property.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the second star in the closing comment, the CF examples all only have one.

Alternatively, use the other syntax:

```
property name="sourceid" type="numeric" default="1";
```

I'm not a fan of annotations in comments for anything other JavaDoc, it just doesn't feel right somehow.